# Android: Show textview for every value in an array (horizontally)

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, kotlin

What is the best practice to achieve a horizontal oriented linearlayout filled with textviews, each for every string in the array. When there is no space left horizontally, I'd like to start my textview on the next line.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a  FlowLayout

Comment: Please add layout what you are trying to achieve via XML or some graphic content for better understanding and save time and efforts.

Comment: I edited my question!

Comment: what about a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`?